# How to prevent skin cracks?

Tags: cold-weather, prevention

So every winter working in the dry cold, my skin, on my hands and feet, cracks. Particularly between my fingers and toes. What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A moisturiser is what you need - personally I like diprobase, you can safely apply as much as you want to and it's not that oily, it soaks into the skin nice and quickly without leaving any horrible residue.

I actually use this all year round because I'm prone to getting bad eczema - so if it does the job on my awful skin, it should help with yours!

Comment: I go for a two-fold approach: when indoors (i.e. in the warm) use creams or lotions that contain water (and also urea) to direcly help hydrating the skin. When outdoors or just before going out when it's freezing, use oily/greasy products such as vaseline/petroleum jelly or bag balm or deer tallow but keep away from products that contain lots of water.

Answer (score 5):

Ideally get a moisturiser that is cream or oil based. For lips and between the fingers, vaseline is excellent at moisturising, then keeping the moisture in.

Answer (score 4):

You should use some kind of moisturizing hand lotion.  There are a lot of brands, and I don't really have a preference.  I like to make sure I get an unscented version, since most moisturizers are market towards women and have floral aromas.  Put it on your skin once or twice a day, and the dry cracking should go away.

Comment: +1 but I still believe that using cloves is the best solution :)

Answer (score 3):

I specifically have problems with splits on the finger tips and found the following helped a lot;

1. Grow your fingernails longer- I used to cut mine very short, this makes a big difference.
2. Use skin cream such as Neutrogena "Norwegian Fishermans Formula". Every time your fingertips feel harder than normal, apply. This will be something like every hour or two in dry weather (ie; heating season).

Comment: I agree with 2 - that Neutrogena stuff is brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

Best. Thing. Ever.

This emollient is moisturizing without being greasy, has a clean, fresh, smell and lasts for a long time between applications. The small, thin tin fits easily in a pocket.

[image: Burtsbees]

Comment: Burts Bees are very good - lots of beeswax products out there just as good too :)

Comment: Personally, the clean, lemony scent of Burt’s is what makes this the product for me.